# Is there a way to find an email message from Outlook inbox via InternetMessageId via C#?

Tags: outlook, office-interop

I have an InternetMessageID for an email item.  I'd like to open a Reply email dialog to an email with this InternetMessageID.  How can I find the email from Outlook API by InternetMessageID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet message id as in "`Message-ID`" MIME header? Use `Items.Find/FindNext` or `Items.Restrict` to search for the `PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_I`D (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F`) property.

Comment: Dmitry, do you have an C# example of code?  I tried this but it didnt work:
    var inbox = app.ActiveExplorer().Session.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    lastItem = inbox.Items.Find("[PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID] = " + replyId);

Error message: The property "PR_INTERNET_MESSAGE_ID" is unknown.

Comment: Try `Find("@SQL=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x1035001F"" = 'somevalue' ")`